# Distribution of succes of a sequence of dependent Bernouilli Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have $N$ dependent Bernoulli Random variables ($X_1,X_2,..X_n$), with the same probability of success $q$. I am wondering whether it is possible to allow for a dependence structure such that there exists a (bounded) continuous distribution for the share of successful Bernoulli Random variables.

I am familiar with the fact that one can approximate also the share of successful of independent Bernoulli Variables as a normal distribution. However, for my specific purpose I prefer not to use an approximation. Especially as I require to have this distribution to be bounded between $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The literal answer is that no, the share of successful variables is in the finite set $\{0,1/n,2/n,\dots, 1\}$ so you can't have a continuous distribution for it.

Although you say that you "prefer not to use an approximation", perhaps you're nonetheless thinking about a setting where $n$ becomes large and you *converge* to a continuous distribution?

Here's just one example of a construction. Let $\mu$ be any probability distribution on $[0,1]$. (For example, $\mu$ could be the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, or whatever.) Take a circle of circumference $1$, and visualise the points $1, 2, \dots, n$ arranged sequentially and equally spaced around the circle. Pick a uniform point $u$ on the circle, and independently pick $Y$ with distribution $\mu$. Draw an arc of length $Y$ clockwise from the point $u$. Set $X_i=1$ if the point $i$ is covered by the arc, and $X_i=0$ otherwise.

Then each $X_i$ is Bernoulli with success probability $\mathbb{E}(Y)$. The proportion of successes is within $1/n$ of $Y$. As $n\to\infty$, the distribution of the proportion of successes converges to $\mu$.